# Need help defining a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I am a newbie to PostgreSQL and am playing around with views. For learning purposes, I have been slowly creating a simple school system.

As of right now, I am trying to define a view with each student's course id, student # and weighted mark for each exam. total_marks(course_id, student_id, marks)

These are my related tables: 
weight(course_id, exam_id, weightage) 
student(student_id) 
course(course_id) 
course_enroll(student_id, course_id) 
exam(exam_id, course_id) 
exam_grade(student_id, exam_id, mark)

So, the view should display all marks from every exam with weightage * mark for corresponding exams. It can show every course. Weightage and Mark are both numeric values. Weightage could be 1.25 and mark could be 84.56. So, you can multiply them together easily.

For example:

| Course_ID | Student_ID | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4321 | 58348 | 96.43% |
| 4322 | 224565 | 40.54% |

Comment: Your data model is missing an `exam` table with a foreign key to `course`, which would allow you to model the data with less redundancy. You didn't explain what the data type and meaning of `weightage` and `mark` are.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I just updated it. Please let me know if this helps in understanding the question.

Comment: Since `exam` now has a foreign key to `course`, you don't need `course_id` in the `weight` table any more. Now join `weight` with `exam_grade` in the only possible way, multiply, sum and group by `student_id` and `course_id`.